# onchange event and auto refresh table after submit

Tags: php, sql, html-table, onchange

1. How do I make the onchange event when I'm choosing an option from my 1st dropdown menu then auto show table without clicking submit?
2. How do I refresh the above table whenever I click submit on the Edit data?

   ```
           <?php

       $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'jared17', 'hbadb') 
       or die ('Cannot connect to db');

       $result = $conn->query("select * from english");

       echo "<html>";
       echo "<body>";
       echo "<form name='form' method = POST>";
       echo "<select name = 'Students'>";
       while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
           $LRN = $row['LRN'];
           $Last = $row['Last_Name']; 
           $First = $row['First_Name'];
           if ($LRN == $_POST['Students']) $selected = 'selected="selected"';
           echo '<option value="'.$LRN.'">'.$Last.', '.$First.'</option>';

       }
        echo "</select>";
       echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Show'>";


       if (isset($_POST['Students'])) {
           $lrn = $_POST['Students'];
           $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Last_Name, First_Name, Level, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, FINAL FROM english WHERE LRN = ?");
           $stmt->bind_param('i', $lrn);
           $stmt->execute();
           $stmt->bind_result($last, $first, $level, $q1, $q2, $q3, $q4, $final);
           $stmt->fetch();
           echo "<table><tr><th>LRN</th><th>Name</th><th>Level</th><th>Q1</th><th>Q2</th><th>Q3</th><th>Q4</th><th>Final</th></tr>";
           echo "<tr><td>$lrn</td><td>$last, $first</td><td>$level</td><td>$q1</td><td>$q2</td><td>$q3</td><td>$q4</td><td>$final</td></tr></table>";
       }
       echo "</form>";

       echo "<form name='form2' method = POST>";
       ///////////EDIT DATA
       echo "Edit Data: ";
       echo "<select name = 'Edit'>";

       echo '<option value=Q1>Q1</option>';
       echo '<option value=Q2>Q2</option>';
       echo '<option value=Q3>Q3</option>';
       echo '<option value=Q4>Q4</option>';
       echo '<option value=FINAL>FINAL</option>';
       echo '<input type="number" name="editdata">';
       echo "</select>";
       echo "<input type='submit' name='submit2' value='Edit Now'>";


       if (isset($_POST['Edit'])) {
           $conn2 = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'jared17', 'hbadb') 
           or die ('Cannot connect to db');
           $upd = $_POST['Edit'];
           $txt = $_POST['editdata'];
           $now = "UPDATE english SET $upd='$txt' WHERE LRN='$lrn'";
           $res = $conn2->query($now);
           if (!$conn2->error) {
               echo "Errormessage: $conn->error";
       }
           echo $now;

       }



       echo "</form>";



       echo "</body>";
       echo "</html>";
       ?>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

All of your questions must be fixed by ajax.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "example.php", //file which has query select to db table
    data: {id:theid},   //describe your value of select option here
    dataType: 'json',   // type of data that will you get (JSON/HTML).
    type: 'POST',       //sending type (POST/GET)
    success: function(data) {
       showTable();
    }
});
```

Comment: could you please give me an example? i'm a newbie here sorry

Comment: For learning ajax, I suggest you to read this api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/